# PHP - comparing strings with special character

Tags: php

I am trying to compare 2 strings that to me look equal, but am not getting a result of equal.

Here is the 2 equality checks I have run:

```
if (strcasecmp($h3Tag, "Sector (GICS®)") == 0) {
    echo "found the sector!<br />";
}

if ($h3Tag == "Sector (GICS®)") {
    echo "found the sector!<br />";
}
```

And here is the print_r for $h3Tag as requested: `Sector (GICS®)`

I am pretty sure it has to do with the registered trademark symbol because I have done a starts with function and got up to that symbol before it failed.  I tried running it through htmlspecialchars and comparing it to `Sector (GICS&reg;)` to no avail.  Any ideas how to compare strings with that symbol?

Comment: can you update your post with `print_r($h3Tag);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out!  Here is the code I had to use:

```
if (strcasecmp($h3Tag, "Sector (GICS&reg;)") == 0) {
                echo "found the sector!<br />";
            }
```

So when I printed or echoed out the $h3Tag it was converting it to the actual symbol.  But to compare to the string, I had to compare to the html code for the symbol.  Maybe this will help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line **header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');** at top.

Also what is it u get when u echo the value of $h3Tag ?

Comment: tried adding the header line, no change unfortunately

Comment: what is the output, when u do **echo $h3Tag;** ?

Comment: `Sector (GICS®)`

Comment: which php version are you using ? you can check by command **php -v** on linux system. the above code you have written is working fine for php version 5.5.9 and above

Comment: 7.0.1 is the version on  my Windows 10